# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'ref' of 'register(...)' as it is undefined when testing React Hook Form V7

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-hook-form

I'm trying to upgrade from React Hook Form V6 to V7. I've been able to do the update, but a few of my tests are broken now. The error that appears is:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'ref' of 'register(...)' as it is undefined.
```

I do some destructuring as the documentation shows:

```
const { register } = useForm();
const { ref, ...rest } = register('test');
```

So, I understand that the error message is regarding this destructure. The component takes the register as a prop. My previous tests worked with this code:

```
const register = jest.fn();
```

This unfortunately does not work any more. I've tried to do a good amount of searching, but all the problems regarding testing of React Hook Form is related to V6.

I have a feeling that you might need to do some mocking, but haven't been able to mock out something that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't give up. After trying a lot of different testing methhods, then it would seem that the answer to my problem was to mock out the jest function.

```js
const register = jest.fn(ref => 'Test');
```